# Unity3D firebase AUTH not working on ANDROID

Tags: c#, android, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-authentication

So, the app I'm making is using firebase auth for registration and login. The registration works, and the user is added to my firebase console in unity editor, on iPhone and on Android. But the login only works in unity editor and on iOS. It won't work on Android and I have no clue why. I tried everything. My code for sign in is basicly the same as here:
https://github.com/misskaseyann/firebase-unity-auth/blob/master/Scripts/Authentication/SignInHandler.cs
only difference is in showing the UI as I don't switch between scenes but enable different panel, something like:

```
void Start()
{
    auth = Firebase.Auth.FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance;
    signinButton.onClick.AddListener(() => {
        SigninWithEmailAsync();
    });
    createAccountButton.onClick.AddListener(() => {
        FindObjectOfType<LoginManagerScript>().LoginPanel.SetActive(false);  
        FindObjectOfType<LoginManagerScript>().RegisterPanel.SetActive(true);
    });
}
```

the signinButton.onClick on android is not working for some reason. Even if I put something else in the listener (like debug) it will not show when I click on it. But it shows in editor and on iPhone. What am I doing wrong here? ADB logcat is saying this when I open the app:

> InvalidOperationException: Don't call Firebase functions before CheckDependencies has finished

I checked the app bundle id and it's the same as in the firebase. The weird thing is that even when I press on my login button, nothing seems to happen. No matter what. Whyy?

Answer (score 1):

YO, I fixed it. It's probably a workaround and not official fix, but it works for me. I made a scene that runs at the start of the application, made a "firebaseinit" game object and put only this class on it for firebase init:

```
public class FirebaseINIT : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static bool firebaseReady;

    void Start()
    {
        CheckIfReady();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if(firebaseReady == true)
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene("LoginScene");
        }
    }

    public static void CheckIfReady()
    {

        Firebase.FirebaseApp.CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync().ContinueWith(task => {
            Firebase.DependencyStatus dependencyStatus = task.Result;
            if (dependencyStatus == Firebase.DependencyStatus.Available)
            {

                Firebase.FirebaseApp app = Firebase.FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance;
                firebaseReady = true;
                Debug.Log("Firebase is ready for use.");
            }
            else
            {
                firebaseReady = false;
                UnityEngine.Debug.LogError(System.String.Format(
                  "Could not resolve all Firebase dependencies: {0}", dependencyStatus));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And now it works on Android too. It seems that Android is having problem with dependency loading or something like that and it does not load the dependencies in time. I could probably put this in my main scene, but this was faster. I hope this helps some body, as I was struggling with this for at least a weak.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind, I'll try to add more context around your answer @sesmajster (and it's a little much to do in the comments).

Your fix is to basically call `CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync`. What this is doing is that on Android, Firebase depends on Google Play Services (GPS) for many of its features. This call will ensure that GPS is available, and prompt the player to upgrade GPS if they're out of date. If the player decides to opt out of updating or has a device without access to GPS (in the US, most commonly the Kindle tablets or VR headsets), you'll get a [`DependencyStatus.Unavailable`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/namespace/firebase#namespace_firebase_1a738891954687d6d8243a285eee9ffb04) result that you could take further action on. Note that on Android, [GPS is not universally required](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/android-play-services) -- it's possible that in the future this call won't be required.

On the desktop platforms (MacOS, Windows, and Linux -- most commonly when developing in the Unity Editor) and in iOS there are no equivalent external dependencies. This call is optional there but still recommended on the off chance that it ever comes up.

For your answer, I will recommend one additional change. What you're doing is a little unsafe, `firebaseReady` should be marked as [`volatile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/volatile) and you can do a little better than polling every frame as well. I'm sure you realized that `ContinueWith` fires on the background thread and can cause some issues in Unity, but Firebase provides an extension method [`ContinueWithOnMainThread`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/class/firebase/extensions/task-extension) that can simplify your code like so:

```
public class FirebaseINIT : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
        CheckIfReady();
    }

    public static void CheckIfReady()
    {

        Firebase.FirebaseApp.CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync().ContinueWithOnMainThread(task => {
            Firebase.DependencyStatus dependencyStatus = task.Result;
            if (dependencyStatus == Firebase.DependencyStatus.Available)
            {

                Firebase.FirebaseApp app = Firebase.FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance;
                SceneManager.LoadScene("LoginScene");
                Debug.Log("Firebase is ready for use.");
            }
            else
            {
                UnityEngine.Debug.LogError(System.String.Format(
                  "Could not resolve all Firebase dependencies: {0}", dependencyStatus));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

(you could also opt for `async`/`await` or using Coroutines, but I figured it would be best to match your current style). I cover this in more detail in [this blog post](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2019/07/firebase-and-tasks-how-to-deal-with.html) and in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5GzFDXvZxKM).